# Hover while dragging

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, hover

I have a scene like this:

```
FlowPane
   AnchorPane
      VBox
         Label
            LabeledText
         HBox
            ImageView
            VBox
               Label
                  LabeledView
         StackPane
            HBox
               ImageView
```

The `FlowPane` has multiple `AnchorPane` nodes. What I need is to have the `AnchorPane` hovered while dragging something over anything that's on it. Just like when I'm not dragging and just moving the mouse over.
I can programmatically trigger the `hover`, using:

```
private static PseudoClass HOVER_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("hover");
anchorePane.pseudoClassStateChanged(HOVER_PSEUDO_CLASS, true);
```

but this only works if the mouse is dragging right on the `AnchorPane` node. If the mouse is dragging over the `label` or `image`...it doesn't hover.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really understand how you're triggering the hover effect by yourself, but I think you shouldn't do that. It can be handled for you automatically by the `setOnDragEntered` and `setOnDragExited` event handlers, you just need to specify the expected behavior. I've made a small example to present how they work.

```
public class JavaFXTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        ImageView avatar = new ImageView("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1eb4610d0e524773a8d28f8896dd5f20?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG");
        avatar.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            Dragboard db = avatar.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putImage(avatar.getImage());
            db.setContent(content);
            e.consume();
        });
        root.setLeft(avatar);

        root.setCenter(getAnchorPane());
        root.setRight(getAnchorPane());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public AnchorPane getAnchorPane() {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
        pane.setOnDragEntered(e -> {
            pane.setStyle("-fx-border-style: dotted;");
        });
        pane.setOnDragExited(e -> {
            pane.setStyle("");
        });
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(pane, 20d);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(pane, 100d);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView("http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png");
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);

        return pane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Firstly I create a stage with one image (my gravatar), which can be dragged, and two identical panels - this is in fact everything the `start` method does.

`getAnchorPane()` method creates the panel and sets its event handlers: if anything is dragged upon it, the panel will change its border to dotted. It doesn't matter if you hover over the panel, or over its child, which is the stackoverflow logo.

[image: Example]